# How to solve Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.MicrosoftDataEntityDesignBootstrapPackage Problem?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I got this error message when I open the project in vs2008

> The Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.MicrosoftDataEntityDesignBootstrapPackage, Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a ({7A4E8D96-5D5B-4415-9FAB-D6DCC56F47FB}) did not load because of previous errors. For assistance, contact the package vendor. To attempt to load this package again, type 'devenv /resetskippkgs' at the command prompt.

Please guide me how to solve. Thanks

Comment: :( no one cannot answer?
I just reinstalled VS but this is not solution.

Comment: Usually you start troubleshooting by starting Visual Studio with /Log switch and looking at the logs. Several times I also had to use Fusion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) since the failure was related to a missing dependency